# How to prevent Hibernate cache?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, caching, jpa

I'm working on an web application using Hibernate 4, Spring 3. I'm struggling with an issue for days.

In the application I have an entity class named 'User':

```
@Entity
public class User {

    @Id
    private int uid;
    @Column(unique = true)
    private String username;
    private String password;
    private boolean confirmed;

    //... getters and setters
}
```

This entity class is mapped from a `table` of db called 'user'.

There is another entity class named 'Confirmation':

```
@Entity
@NamedQueries({
        @NamedQuery(name = "getAllConfirmations", query = "select c from Confirmation c")
})
public class Confirmation {

    @Id
    private String username;
    private boolean confirmed;

    //... getters and setters    
}
```

This entity class is mapped from a `view` of db called 'confirmation'.

```
create view confirmation
as 
select username,confirmed from user
```

I have a method in my service class to get list of all Confirmation object:

```
public List<Confirmation> getListOfConfirmations() {
    Query query = entityManager.createNamedQuery("getAllConfirmations");
    return query.getResultList();
}
```

Also, there's a method to confirm User objects- set confirmed field 'true':

```
public int confirmUser(int uid) {
    User user = getUser(uid);
    if (user != null) {
        user.setConfirmed(true);
        try {
            entityManager.getTransaction().begin();
            entityManager.merge(user);
            entityManager.getTransaction().commit();
            return 1;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

When I call `confirmUser()` it works fine and User object and it's row in database would be changed, But when I call `getListOfConfirmations()` after changes no change would be viewed in the result list.

It seems, by default, hibernate caches query result of views.

Is there any way to prevent hibernate to prevent caches this result.

In addition, I've tried `@Cacheable(false)` for Confirmation class or set `@QueryHint(name = "org.hibernate.cacheable", value = "false")` for `getAllConfirmations` named query, these don't work.

Persistence config:

```
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" version="2.0">
     <persistence-unit name="MyPU" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
         <provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>

         <class>bob.jpacache.Confirmation</class>
         <class>bob.jpacache.User</class>

         <exclude-unlisted-classes>false</exclude-unlisted-classes>
         <properties>
             <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
             <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect"/>
             <property name="hibernate.connection.url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost/cachetest"/>
             <property name="hibernate.connection.username" value="root"/>
             <property name="hibernate.connection.password" value="root"/>
             <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update"/>
             <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true"/>
             <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="true"/>
         </properties>
     </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

Thanks, in advance, for your help.

Answer (score 1):

@Cacheable refers to the second-level cache and your problem seems to me that it is in the first level cache. I believe that the problem is in the life cycle of your EntityManager (at what time you create a new, at what time you close it), do a simple test: after the change of the User's objects, try call entityManager.clear () and then query your Confirmation object. NOTE: entityManager.clear () must be called on the same EntityManager that will be used to make the query.

Another detail, do not know what his real purpose, but the query has no filter. Thus, whether the User has to confirm or not, will always bring all records of User table.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Marlon. EntityManager.clear() works but it clears whole cache. I think it forces jpa recreate new cache and cuases slow down issue. If this is a level-1 issue so according to hibernate documentation we would not be able to prevent caching.

Comment: @Babak normally this problem is a programming error.  It is difficult to assess without understanding the whole context , but as I said it may be a matter of opening a new EntityManager.